# How to use build parameters in the pieline.agent.node block of a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, parameter-passing, jenkins-2

I'm developing a Jenkins pipeline for a PHP project. Since I want to run the most of the steps from the project's root directory, I set the `customWorkspace`:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'devvm-slave-01'
            customWorkspace '/path/to/my/project'
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine, but I don't like, that the path is hard-coded in the `Jenkinsfile`.

So I tried to solve this by using parameters:

[image]

The problem is: I haven't found a way to access parameters in the block `pipeline.agent.node`. I can read and handle them in the `pipeline.stages.stage.steps` sections. But not in the `node` block.

**Is it possible / How to access Jenkins project parameters in the `node` section of the `Jenkinsfile`?**

Comment: Have you tried `customWorkspace PROJECT_ROOT`? Works for me.

Comment: @zett42 Hey! Thank you very much! I tried different variants, but all of them were with the `$` like: `$PROJECT_ROOT` or `${params.PROJECT_ROOT}`. Now it works! Btw. `env.PROJECT_ROOT` and `params.PROJECT_ROOT` are working as well. Feel free to create an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the parameter instead of hard-coded value for `customWorkspace` like this:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent {
        node {
            label 'devvm-slave-01'
            customWorkspace PROJECT_ROOT
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('build') {
            steps {
                sh 'pwd'
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```